# Two iframes side by side, left one is a sidebar with links that would open in the right iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

What is the best practice for HTML with two iframes side by side, when the left one is a sidebar that contains links which will open other html pages on the right iframe when clicking on them?

Something like that:
[image]

Comment: I do not think this type of question fits on this site.

Comment: Are the `iframes` on the same server? have the same domain?

Comment: @EnigmaRM Yes, both of them on my server and domain

Comment: @Neal thanks for the downvote, i guess. Great encouragement from you to learning and education. Hope you act different with your peers.

Comment: @StasS Why do you want to go with an `iframe` in the first place? If all of the data resides on the server/domain there are other ways to have the page be more interactive. What you're describing is essentially a single page app.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have control of all the content, or at the very least, you have control over the menu, you could use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to achieve this.

1. Script in the menu iframe posts a message to the parent html page - `window.top` -  when a link is clicked
2. Script in the parent page receives the message and parses the desired url from the message's `data`property
3. Parent page script alters the iframe src attribute to the desired url

However, as far as best practice is concerned, there isn't a best practice for the use case you describe, it's best avoided if possible.

The short version is that iframes are an an uneccessary complication, and best avoided. You lose a lot of flexibility and they always bite you in the butt sooner or later. A more detailed explanation, which I agree with, can be found here: [Why the Iframe is Evil](http://www.rwblackburn.com/iframe-evil/)

As all your content is on the same server, I would recommend that you consider using AJAX practices to load in the content of the pages, so that they are a direct part of the html page. Some of the advantages this will bring are:

- loaded content will use the same css as the parent page
- loaded content can be manipulated with the same javascript as the parent page
- the container div will resize to fit content by default, less scrollbars on the page
- you won't need to learn any exotic stuff like postMessage until you really need or want to

A quick and easy way to try this out is to use jQuery, and it's [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function.
I've made a short codepen to show example code that you should be able to try out on your project. Note that it won't work at all in codepen.

In their case, the code window is at s.codepen.io and the pages I link are in codepen.io - as there is no access-control-allow-origin policy which lets s. load pages from codepen.io, the browser doesn't load anything.

http://codepen.io/daveycakes/pen/MbOmEB

Comment: Thanks. Why should it be avoided? I would be happy to learn what is bad here and how should i approach this challenge differently.

Comment: The article "Why the iframe is evil" has been moved here: https://www.blackburnlabs.com/iframe-evil/